# urlencode does not convert HTML

Tags: php

Why is urlencode($Data) not encoding? When I post my form, the data is being inserted into the Database as:

```
%3Cdiv+id%3D%22main-wrap%22+class%3D%22clearfix%22%3E
```

Which should be:

```
<div id="main-wrap" class="clearfix">
```

Ideas?

I have tried this as advised below but it still does not work:

```
$DataEncoded = urlencode($Data);
echo $DataEncoded;
echo urldecode($DataEncoded);
```

Comment: Unecessary; if you're using bound params to get the HTML into your database from a `<textarea>` you can just do something like `$stmt->bindParam(1, $_POST['data'], PDO::PARAM_STR);` - no need to mess about with URL encoding at all (though you'd probably want a `!empty()` sanity check).

Answer (score 2):

You need to decode the data, not encode it. See [urldecode](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php).

Comment: ... or **no** URL encoding/decoding function at all if it's **_POST** data from a `<textarea>` form field; you don't need it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to decode the encoded data, like this:

```
$html = '<div id="main-wrap" class="clearfix">';
$encoded = urlencode($html);
echo $encoded;
echo urldecode($encoded);
```

This outputs:

```
%3Cdiv+id%3D%22main-wrap%22+class%3D%22clearfix%22%3E
<div id="main-wrap" class="clearfix">
```

Comment: I tried this and it still made no difference... See the edited Q above.

Comment: You need to use `urldecode` on the value _going into the database_. You can't treat it like a pointer.